Google Apps Script Combo Bar / Line Chart with 2 Y Axis
I am working within Google Apps Script, and trying to create a combo bar / line chart.
Here's my client side code for generating the chart:
    function displayCo2Charts(JSONObj) {
      var retObj = JSON.parse(JSONObj);
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(retObj.co2MonthData);

      var options = {
        title : 'CO2 Emissions by Month',
        vAxis: {title: 'Emissions'},
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Month',
          baseline:0,
          minorGridlines:0,
        },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        width:900,
        height: 500,
        series: {
          1: {type: 'line'},
        },
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('co2MonthDiv'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

And the data that is being sent:
co2MonthData = [["Month", "Emissions", "Average"]
, ["2024 Jan", "4.995", "0.208"]
, ["2024 Feb", "7.056", "0.157"]
, ["2024 Mar", "3.268", "0.102"]
, ["2024 Apr", "0.083", "0.028"]
]

And here's what I get:

That's great, but the Average is so small compared to the total that it's not really legible here.  So now I need to make a change so that the average series appears on a separate axis.  Here's the updated code I've found to do that, essentially adding to the series object indicators so that series 1 (the line) gets attached to targetAxisIndex:1.
    function displayCo2Charts(JSONObj) {
      //console.log(JSONObj);
      var retObj = JSON.parse(JSONObj);
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(retObj.co2MonthData);

      var options = {
        title : 'CO2 Emissions by Month',
        vAxis: {title: 'Emissions'},
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Month',
          baseline:0,
          minorGridlines:0,
        },
        seriesType: 'bars',
        width:900,
        height: 500,
        series: {
          0: {targetAxisIndex:0},  //this was added
          1: {type: 'line', targetAxisIndex:1},  //this was updated
        },
        vAxes: {  //added at DuuEyn's suggestion, and this set the right title
          1: {
            title:"Average Emissions"
          }
        },
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('co2MonthDiv'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }

That mostly works, in that the line is now clearly on a different axis, which is great.  But the left axis loses the numbers indicting the values, values don't appear on the right axis either, and the legend moved from the side to the top, and lost their labels.

Are there settings in the options object that I need to set correctly to get values on both the left and right axis?  And can I give each of the two axis a different title?  I tried adding a title:'average' value to the series object just in case, but that didn't work.  (EDIT: I added the vAxes block, which did allow me to set different titles.)

Can you share an example of the data table you're using to render the chart? In addition, I suggest adding a vAxes property to your options object. You can check the combo chart's configuration options for more info.

@DuuEyn Thank you for the tips.  I did add vAxes (and I removed vAxis, I just didn't edit that correctly above), and the titles are correct now.  However, now I'm seeing that my real issue has to do with when the div this is written to becomes visible.  If the div is visible {$('#divId').show()} when chart.draw() runs, the left & right values do appear.  If the div is NOT visible {$('#divId').hide()} when chart.draw() runs, the left & right values do not appear.  This div is in a "tab" that is set to hide() on open, so I think I need to look more that process now.

You're welcome @Andrew. Regarding the new issue you mentioned, this post might help. I also recommend creating a new post regarding it in case you have additional questions as the issue you're now encountering is no longer the same as the one in your original post.  If my answer helped you, do consider accepting or upvoting it so other people in the community, who may have a similar concern, will know that it can be resolved.

Workaround:
I've modified your existing script and removed vAxis from options as it conflicts with vAxes. I've also modified vAxes and added a title for each series 0 and 1.
Try this code snippet:


google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function() {
    var co2MonthData = [
      [{
          label: "Month",
          type: "string"
        },
        {
          label: "Emissions",
          type: "number"
        },
        {
          label: "Average",
          type: "number"
        },
      ],
      ["2024 Jan", 4.995, 0.208],
      ["2024 Feb", 7.056, 0.157],
      ["2024 Mar", 3.268, 0.102],
      ["2024 Apr", 0.083, 0.028]
    ];

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(co2MonthData);

    var options = {
      title: 'CO2 Emissions by Month',
      //Removed vAxis as it conflicts with vAxes
      //modified vAxes to add a title for both series 0 and 1
      vAxes: {
        0: {
          title: "Emissions"
        },
        1: {
          title: "Average Emissions"
        }
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Month',
        baseline: 0,
        minorGridlines: 0,
      },
      seriesType: 'bars',
      width: 900,
      height: 500,
      series: {
        0: {
          targetAxisIndex: 0
        },
        1: {
          type: 'line',
          targetAxisIndex: 1
        },
      },
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('co2MonthDiv'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="co2MonthDiv"></div>



EDIT:
In case the snippet's not rendering properly, here's a screenshot of the results after modifying options when rendering the chart:

